# Web API for default beep/ding/warning/alert/buzz/no-no sound

Tags: javascript, browser, webapi

On most platforms, there is some sort of "no" sound when some sort of exceptional thing or alert occurs.

On Windows, we had the classic ding sound, with now a more friendly sound accompanying the notification bar.  On OS X, we have the donk sound, that goes with alert boxes.  Even on mobile with the speakers muted, we typically end up a short vibration motor pulse.

Is there a browser API for triggering this sort of "default" attention-seeking sound or vibration without popping up an alert box or notification?

(Note:  I realize we can play sounds with the audio element and Web Audio API, and I also realize there is an experimental API for buzzing the vibration motor.  I'm not interested in managing those behaviors myself.  I want to trigger the default alert sound/buzz action on whatever device/platform is in use.)

Comment: I'm pretty doubtful there is such an option

Comment: U could use  vibration using navigators or use play sound on notification .... But I don't think  web has something like this !

Comment: What is the use case for having this without the notification to pop out? Is having that notification even for a second that big of deal? The Notification API is currently the only one able to access the OS notification system which is responsible for this behavior, so something like `const notif = new Notification("ding dong", { vibrate: true }); 
notif.onshow = e => setTimeout(() => notif.close(), 200);` is about the closest you'll get (though the notification sound is not necessarily the error one)

Comment: @Kaiido I don't have a particular use case in mind, but it's a commonly used functionality, and a best practice to use the platform's UI elements, including sound.  An example might be a web-based terminal emulator that needs to support the "bell" character `^G`, which these days usually maps to that default sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in any browser as of the time of writing (except for [vibration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API) on supported devices/browsers). An alternative approach is to serve a sound to the user, based on the [user-agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) (used for detecting the device) using the [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) api (though if you don't want to manage this behaviour yourself, this is obviously a straight no unless there is a pre-existing library somehwere).